# Cygwin rSnapshot on windows Permission denied, while permissions are retained

Tags: windows, cygwin, permission-denied

I know there are a lot of cases close to this, but I have not found any that matches my circumstances.

Quite a few of our clients backup large quantities of data using cygwin.

The general environment is:
A windows based virtual domain controller (host is esxi, but that is irrelevant)
The backup is going to an external encrypted raid device. which the system sees as a normal usb attached hard disk.

OS tends to mainly be sbs2011 / 08, in some rare cases sbs03.

Cygwin, usually the latest version as it is kept up to date. and its snapshot package.
The rsnapshot conf file is not really changed from its origianl state with the exception of target and destination, and some exclusions.

The backup is triggered by a batch, which starts cygwins rsnapshot rsync process creating a backup from the windows server to the attached storage in (hourly x2 daily x5 weekly x4 monthlyx6 backups.)

The source files are rsynced to the destination. the original order of the permissions is not preserved but the necessary permissions are kept, ie source has the group and a user admin with full access, the target has both but with special permissions, and within special, full access is granted.

When rsnapshot moves hourly0 to hourly1 it completes. all the files are linked properly. but it takes a long time due to every file getting a "could not link (cygdrive/x/x/hourly.0/path to file/file /cygdrive/x/x/hourly.1/path to file/file Permission denied)

args is commented out because anything put into args ie -av etc does not work and nore does it need to as the destination in another way does have administratoren and admin with full permissions.

cygwin is installed using admin on the admin account, task scheduler is set to admin, and the tasks are run by the admin account with full access.

The backing up process works. I believe the issue lies in the destination, I can understand that it could be related to issues between posix and acl but do not believe it is the cause as again, the permissions are granted.

So I am asking the most experienced out there, if you have any ideas, things to try, change. Please could you let me know clearly.

Kindest regards and appreciation.

Dan